# eclipse debug view arranging code to debug

Tags: eclipse, debugging

I had this arranged nicely and after creating a new wrokspace I cant quite get it arranged the way I would like it to.
Here is a screen grab:[image]

I would like the stack trace tab ( the one that appears as the top pane in image ) to appear vertically on the left and my code to display alongside it on the right 
Essentially a side by side view rather than vertically.

I did a cursory search but maybe I do not know the right keyword in Google / SO to search for what I am looking for.

Comment: ok I think I will close this question . Opened Java perspective >> window >> show view >> debug. Then the debug view I could simply drag into the left hand side area and now code and debugging can happen side by side rather than vertical

Comment: or on second thoughts - will let it remain if this is useful for someone else ( including me in future :) )

Comment: That **is** the default in the current release. Just Reset the Perspective from the Window menu when in the Debug perspective.

Comment: ok one interesting thing is that if I set a breakpoint and if code hits the breakpoint the perspective again shifts to 'debug' and view again becomes vertical panes. I then have to again click on the java perspective to get the views aligned side by side

Comment: You need to drag the debug view while the debug perspective is open. Just like you did while the Java perspective was open. Each perspective save it's own view layout.

Comment: yep thanks dragging the debug view when eclipse defaulted the breakpoint to a breakpoint perspective did the trick.The horizontal layout of the debug view became vertical :) please can you submit your suggestion as an answer will gladly accept it